# How to select a variable upon selection of another in arm templates?

Tags: azure, azure-rm-template

I'm very new to ARM templates(like terraform than ARM but, I got no choice DevTest Labs doe snot support Terraform templates to read and deploy from a github repository).
I'm trying to write a template to deploy a market place image which has two plans.

Image reference

```
"11.1": {
            "publisher": "publisher",
            "offer": "offer",
            "sku": "SkuA",
            "version": "latest"
        },
        "12.0": {
            "publisher": "publisher",
            "offer": "offer",
            "sku": "skuB",
            "version": "latest"
        },
```

Plans

```
        "plan11": {
            "name": "nameA",
            "publisher": "publisher",
            "product": "Product"
        },
        "plan12": {
            "name": "NameB",
            "publisher": "publisher",
            "product": "product"

        }
```

I need to get only input from user on the image selection and based on that auto select the plan.
how can I achieve this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

There is one great solution for your problem:

First you can specify parameter image like this:

```
"identityType": {
    "type": "string",
    "defaultValue": "None",
    "metadata": {
        "description": "Type of managed service identity. - SystemAssigned, UserAssigned, None."
    }
}
```

Then in the section variable you can create all possible solutions like this - in your case plans with image:

```
"identityProperties": {
    "None": {
        "type": "None"
    },
    "SystemAssigned": {
        "type": "SystemAssigned"
    },
    "UserAssigned": {
        "type": "UserAssigned,SystemAssigned",
        "userAssignedIdentities": {
            "[resourceId('Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/userAssignedIdentities', parameters('identityName'))]": {}
        }
    }
}
```

Then the only thing remaining is to specify the parameter and the variable that goes with the value of the parameter:

```
"identity": "[variables('identityProperties')[parameters('identityType')]]"
```

**Make sure to the name the variable values in my case None,SystemAssigned,UserAssigned same as the parameter value that you are providing**